Box lose shape while scrolling LazyRow

I have a problem, when i scroll my LazyRow, boxes which going out from it lose their shape. I am using a modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)) and if item is visible in row it clips, but if not it lose shape. I know it sounds weird, but you can see it on the screenshot.
Here is my composable function:

@Composable
fun ChartCaloriesSection(
    allCalorieData: List<DayCalorieData>,
    requiredCalorieAmount: Int
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(210.dp)
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
        shadowElevation = 2.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Calories statistics",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
            )
            val basicFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
            val sortedCalorieData = allCalorieData.sortedBy {
                LocalDate.parse(it.date, basicFormatter)
            }

            LazyRow(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                    start = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp
                ),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp)
            ) {
                items(sortedCalorieData, key = { data -> data.date }) { data ->
                    Column(
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .animateItem()
                    ) {
                        val uiFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM")
                        val date = LocalDate.parse(data.date, basicFormatter)
                        val outputDateString = date.format(uiFormatter)

                        var progress by rememberSaveable { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
                        LaunchedEffect(key1 = requiredCalorieAmount, key2 = data.receivedCaloriesAmount) {
                            progress = if(requiredCalorieAmount == 0) {
                                0f
                            } else {
                                (data.receivedCaloriesAmount - data.spentCaloriesAmount).toFloat() / requiredCalorieAmount.toFloat()
                            }
                        }
                        val percentFromRequired by animateFloatAsState(
                            targetValue = progress,
                            label = "progress animation",
                            animationSpec = tween(1000)
                        )

                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .width(20.dp)
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceDim),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter,
                        ) {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .fillMaxHeight(percentFromRequired)
                                    .background(
                                        Brush.verticalGradient(
                                            colors = listOf(
                                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                            )
                        }

                        Text(
                            text = outputDateString,
                            fontSize = 13.sp,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried to change positions of modifiers in parent box, tried to change weight(1f) to height(100.dp) in parent box, tried to remove Modifier.animateItem() from the main column, tried to add clip to the child box. But nothing help. Thank you in advance

The code you provided doesn't exhibit the problem you described. Can you create a [mre]?

The background modifier also accepts a Shape as a parameter. To resolve the issue, instead of using clip, you should provide the shape directly to the background modifier.
.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceDim, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))


your solution worked for me but I am not getting a reason why do we need to pass shape in the background. Can you share a bit more details about your solution?

This solution worked for me when I faced a similar issue, although I haven't pinpointed the root cause yet.
